# url rewrite / redirect apache server

Tags: redirect, rewrite

How would I get `sub.domain.com` OR `http://sub.domain.com`

to do a redirect to `https://sub.domain.com`

Thanks!

Comment: A little more information on your platform would be helpful.

Comment: What programming language? What webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache Web Server, add this to your .htaccess file:

```
Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
```

Then restart apache. Good luck!

Comment: What if i needed just one particular subdomain to do this? like test.domain.com or http://test.domain.com  to redirect to https://test.domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache and have mod_rewrite you could add the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule /(.*) https://sub.domain.com [R,L]
```

This redirects you to https only if you are not using https. If you want this to only apply to certain domains then use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.domain.com$
RewriteRule /(.*) https://sub.domain.com [R,L]
```